# What are the symptoms of salt poisoning?

Tags: symptoms, toxicity, salt

I used a large amount of salt yesterday. Now (after 19 hours) I'm feeling ill. Although I do not think it is my case, I am curious: What amount of salt is toxic? What are the symptoms of salt poisoning? How many hours does it usually take to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Too much salt in the body is known as [hypernatremia](https://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/endocrine-and-metabolic-disorders/electrolyte-disorders/hypernatremia), and the symptoms are fairly straightfoward. You get very thirsty.

> The major symptom of hypernatremia is thirst. The absence of thirst in
>   conscious patients with hypernatremia suggests an impaired thirst
>   mechanism. Patients with difficulty communicating or ambulating may be
>   unable to express thirst or obtain access to water. Sometimes patients
>   with difficulty communicating express thirst by becoming agitated.

Treatment is to drink a lot of water (and quit eating so much salt). Your kidneys will do the rest to restore your normal sodium levels.

Frankly, hypernatremia isn't particularly dangerous. What is dangerous is the opposite, hyponatremia.